# When attempting to run application in Android Studio emulator, an image appears as an editor tab instead

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm doing a simple Android application here, but when I go to run the application on the emulator, instead of the application loading, an image appears in the editor. This image is the same image that I previously had in an ImageView object on the main activity.

I have since deleted this object, but something has happened with the file that now loads this image instead of running the application. I've included a screen shot after pressing "run". I cannot find the file in the project folder or manifest.

[image]

What have I done here?

Answer (score 1):

Check the run configuration for the app. In the drop down to the left of the run button, where it says "app" and has the little Android icon, choose Edit Configurations. In the dialog that pops up, check these things:

- For Module, it should be Festival_Tickets.app.main.
- Under Installation Options, Deploy should be "Default APK".
- Under Launch Options, Launch should be "Default Activity".

All other options should be unchecked or blank.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I checked the configurations and they do align with your answer.